# Editing the default page to show all posts, rather than most recent ones

Tags: posts, homepage, customization

I'm trying to edit the default post-page of WordPress so that it displays all posts as opposed to the most recent 10, but I'm unsure which file to edit.

I tried to edit wp_get_recent_posts function in wp-includes/post.php, but it had no effect. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
function wp_get_recent_posts( $args = array(), $output = ARRAY_A ) {

if ( is_numeric( $args ) ) {
    _deprecated_argument( __FUNCTION__, '3.1', __( 'Passing an integer number of posts is deprecated. Pass an array of arguments instead.' ) );
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => absint( $args ) );
}

// Set default arguments.
$defaults = array(
    'numberposts' => 1000, 'offset' => 0,
    'category' => 0, 'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC', 'include' => '',
    'exclude' => '', 'meta_key' => '',
    'meta_value' =>'', 'post_type' => 'post', 'post_status' => 'draft, publish, future, pending, private',
    'suppress_filters' => true
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to set "post_per_page" to "-1". Add this code to your home or index.php.

WP_Query (recommended)

```
$args = array('posts_per_page' => -1);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
  while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    the_title();
    the_content();
  endwhile;

  /* Restore original Post Data */
  wp_reset_postdata();

} else {
  // no posts found
}
```

query_posts() way

```
// Args that you pass to loop
$args = array('posts_per_page' => -1);

// The Query
query_posts( $args );

// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    the_title();
    the_content();
endwhile;

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
```

Alternatively you can go to Dashboard -> Settings -> Reading and set maximum posts per page to "1000" or something.

Comment: `query_posts` is not recommended. Please use WP_Query. Check [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/43098) for more info

Comment: @bravokeyl well you're right, I just wanted to give him quick solution (post_per_page). Just added WP_Query code to the answer, cheers.